# Optional participation in database design and crow's foot notation

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relationship, entity-relationship, option-type

Given a relationship such that:

TAXI -> has -> ROUTE -> driven by -> ASSIGNED_TRANSPORT

Is the relationship from route to assigned_transport, zero, one or many (that is, a one-to-many connectivity with optional participation, **OR** would it be a one to many (that is, mandatory participation rather than optional participation)?

That is, I don't understand optional participation, could you correctly argue that when a route is newly assigned by the taxi company, it will most likely have no assigned_transport assigned to it yet at a given point in time (of course later it most certainly will). Is this how you could correctly argue for optional participation?

Basically I am confused as to how to judge whether there is an optional participation between two entities...

I suppose on the contrary, you could also argue that, if there is an entity instance in the assigned_transport table, you would expect that an assigned_transport instance to be assigned to a particular route (otherwise, there would be no point in assigning transport if it has no route!)... hence assigned_transport would be mandatory, not optional?

So I'm not sure which of it is logically correct...

Am I on the correct track?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference to be kept in mind between conceptual/logical models and physical models.

In a physical model, the child end of a one-to-many is nearly always optional if for no other reason than you can't insert the child until the parent is persisted because of declarative referential integrity constraints.  There can be exceptions to this, but in general you insert a parent before you insert any children.  Therefore, if only just for a fleeting moment, the parent has zero children.

In a conceptual or logical model, the point is to record your business rules.  Your business rules don't need to account for a technological limitation of your RDBMS.  Therefore you can be free to model a one-to-one-or-more relationship if your business rules indicate that the parent makes no sense without children.

In the case of your example, it is hard to say, since I don't know your business rules.  If nobody is driving a ROUTE, does that route actually exist?  That is what you have to decide when you build your conceptual and logical models.  When you build a physical model you will almost certainly end up with optional ASSIGNED_TRANSPORT participation just because of your DRI.

Comment: Thank you Joel. One question, when you asserted that the child end of a one-to-many is nearly always optional and if I understood correctly, explained how this is a consequence of declarative referential integrity constraints, doesn't this make the child end of the one-to-many a mandatory participation rather than optional since you cannot add the child unless the parent exists? Thus, what you said isn't also consistent with how you mentioned "for a fleeting moment, the parent has zero children"? How does this occur if you can't add the child without the existence of the parent entity first?

Comment: Furthermore, I will proclaim that yes, the route (defines only the origin and destination locations) actually exists even if nobody is driving a route, hence does that make the ASSIGNED_TRANSPORT optional to ROUTE as a consequence?

Whereas if I had said for the business rules that, if nobody is driving a ROUTE, the route will not exist, doesn't this still imply it is **still a optional participation** since if nobody is driving a ROUTE, this just implies that the child has no entity occurrences, which is OK isn't it? (Since the parent ROUTE exists, so no DRI is violated)

Am I misguided?

Comment: @Restricted - To the contrary, the child end of a one to many will generally be optional in a physical model.  Remember that the cardinality in a crows-foot diagram has to be read from the frame of reference of the related entity.  The child sees a mandatory parent because you can't have the child until the parent is there (so says the foreign key constraint).  At the same time, the parent sees children as optional since the parent must exist first before any children are added.

Comment: If you define routes whether or not they are _ever_ driven, then yes it makes sense to have ROUTE records with zero ASSIGNED_TRANSPORT, and so assigned transport is optional.  If, on the other hand, you say that a ROUTE that is never driven is not of interest (i.e. won't be stored in the database) then ASSIGNED_TRANSPORT is (logically at least) **mandatory** to ROUTE.  If the parent has cardinality 0 if and only if the child has cardinality 0 then this is _not_ optionality.

Comment: Thank you. Your first response fully makes sense and I can fully comprehend that. However, in regards to your last sentence of the subsequent response following the first, would you perhaps have any further examples or references that has any further examples to fully clarify this? I am still unable to fully grasp the participation concept to a satisfying extent. To add on, currently, I am only concerned with the conceptual model.

Comment: @Restricted - To clarify, when the parent record doesn't exist, it does not make sense to say the non-existence of a child record implies optionality.  It only makes sense to talk about the optionality of a child record in the context of an existing parent record.  You can say that a woman may have zero, one or more sons (offspring is optional) but you would not say that a woman may have zero one or more lungs (at least one lung is mandatory to live).

Comment: A woman may have zero one or more lungs, could that statement ever be true for a certain business rule? i.e. During a lung transplant from a, say, brain-dead individual, this individual will have zero lungs. Would this imply optionality? Or, does this satisfy your statement "it does not make sense to say the non-existence of a child record implies optionality" such that the non-existence of a lung for a particular individual at a given point in time does not imply optionality? And thus, for the particular situation I have just delineated, is actually mandatory particip. rather than optional?

Comment: @Restricted - Everything always depends on your business rules.  There is no point in a conceptual model allowing for things that are outside of the scope of your business.  If you have a business that needs to track women without lungs then this would not be an example of a mandatory (1 or many) relationship.  If your business rule says that you will never need or want to save a particular parent record without at least one child record related to it, then your conceptual model will reflect this with a mandatory one-to-many (i.e. exactly 1 to 1 or more) relationship.